# Context Provider not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, coingecko

This is the code.

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])
const [sortedCoins, setSortedCoins] = useState([])
```

With `useEffect`, I request from an API code and store it in coins, then I store that same data in `sortedCoins`, then with this function I sort through that (There might be some missing `}` because its only one part of the function, essentially this is the part that sorts the data by name).

```
const sort = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.getAttribute("name");

    if (name === "cryptonames") {
      let temp = coins;

      temp = temp.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        
      });

      setSortedCoins(temp);
}
```

Now on another component I do this:

```
{sortedCoins.map((coin) => {
        return <SpecificCoin key={coin.id} {...coin}></SpecificCoin>;
      })}
```

My problem is, even though the sorting is successful and the `sortedCoins` is an array sorted by names (I am using CoinGecko API for cryptocurrencies), my `SpecificCoin` list is not re-rendered, it stays the default way.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can't say that I understood your question completely to be honest, but I can see there's something wrong with your sort function

```
      let temp = coins;
```

Do not equate an array with a variable because it doesn't create a copy of the array, and any changes to `temp` means you're directly mutating the `coins` state variable, which will not cause a re-render if any changes were to be made to it. Try

```
let temp = [...coins]
```

or

```
let temp = coins.slice()
```

Secondly,

```
temp = temp.sort((a, b) => {
...
```

`sort()` on an array changes the array itself, so no need to do this, instead go for

```
 temp.sort((a, b) => {
    ...
```

Then when you do `setSortedCoins(temp)`, it might cause a re-render, because you will have followed the prescribed ways of updating an array state variable

Comment: So me and a friend found another way to fix this, essentially we ran the function in a useTimeout, firstly we set the sortedCoins array to empty, then the logic on Temp variable and then setSortedCoins(temp). That worked pretty well because my friend said React can't detect whether the state of an array with objects changed if only the order of the objects had changed.
However, your method works perfectly man, I can't quite put my finger to why it's working so well tho ?
Can you explain further to a react noob as to why now it's rendering succesfully?

Comment: Yes of course. You see, a component in react re-renders when there's a change in its state, props or context which it is using. Now, what your `sort` function was doing, like I said, was equating a state variable (`coins`), which is an array, to another variable `temp`. This doesn't mean that temp is a duplicate of coins, but instead temp refers to coins (that's how arrays and variable assigning works). Now if you made ANY change to `temp`, it also mutated/changed `coins` in a way React deems unlawful, because the only way you should've changed `coins` was through `setCoins`.

Comment: How did `coins` mutate? Well, when you ran `temp.sort()`, you actually ran `coins.sort()` (remember, `temp` refers to `coin` because you used a simple `=` there), and `Array.prototype.sort()` function modifies the array it operates on, so it sorted the `coins` array. This didn't trigger a re-render, but the `coins` array was rearranged. Through my way, you never make a change to the `coins` array, instead you create a copy of it, sort the copy, and THEN set the copy to the other state variable `sortedCoins`. So, `coins` array was untouched, and you got `sortedCoins` sorted, which you used.

Comment: Alright man, thank you so much. Now it makes more sense, I come from a Java background so temp = coins to me looked like I was just getting the value from coins and assigning it to temp, without temp pointing to coins tho.
Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. Kindly leave an upvote if this helped you out!